# Navigate to a specific page by url in React

Tags: reactjs, url, navigation

How do I navigate to a specific page with url in React?
I realized I've used CRA in the past and haven't really tackled this specifically.

Currently I'm rendering ReactDOM with BrowserRouter and Switch with exact path in Routes

```
// index.jsx
/* eslint-disable import/extensions */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import App from './app/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

```
// App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import HomePage from '../pages/Home';
import PlansPage from '../pages/Plans';
import NotFoundPage from '../pages/NotFound';

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/plans" component={PlansPage} />
      <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

```
// webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: false,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'style-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }, {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }],
      },
    ],
  },
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({}),
  ],
};
```

Navigating to `http://localhost:8080/plans` leads to a page with `Cannot GET /plans`.  However, clicking on a `Link` element navigates to that plans page without an issue.

Comment: Are you using CRA or no cli with custom webpack config?

Comment: @Jorden this one is without CRA.  I'm going with custom webpack config

Comment: I think you need to wrap Header and Switch, becuase BrowserRouter should have only one child

Comment: Are you using webpack dev server for your config? if so I know what your problem is cause I had the exact problem months and it fixed my issue.

Comment: @jorden hmm, actually I'm not using dev server. :/

Comment: Just to clarify the issue your having is you can click on links and it'll navigate to your route pages but if you try to manually type in the URL browser your route or refresh the page on that route it'll give you `Cannot get` the route name correct?

Comment: @jorden yes, that's right.

Comment: I've added my webpack config.  When I build, I get a warning that the assets exceed the recommended size limit, and I think maybe that has to do with this issue.  Maybe?

Comment: What is listening at port 8080? Is it an express server or something similar?

Comment: i have backend in another folder which I'm not currently working with, just the frontend react app at 8080.  `"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"`

Comment: @Jorden i just realized that i'm running with `webpack-dev-server`...

Comment: ah, i think i figured it out guys, i added `devServer` config with `historyApiFallback` in the webpack, and I think that solved it.  I know @Jorden mentioned this earlier, so I want to give him a chance to respond with an answer.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah since you're using webpack Dev Server all you have to do is add `historyApiFallback=true` and it'll fix you issue. You're essentially telling all routes to fall back to your index.html file. Hope that helped.